# How to move to next scene in Unity using c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make a script that moves from the scene LoadScene  to scene SampleScene when user click on button.

```
   using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UIGame : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Button newGame;
    void Start()
    {
        newGame.onClick.AddListener(StartNewGame);
    }
    private void StartNewGame()
    {
        ScenesManager.Instance.LoadNewGame();
    }

}
```

And  moves from the scene SampleScene to scene LoadScene:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UIGame : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Button Home;

    void Start()
    {
        Home.onClick.AddListener(StartHome);
    }
    private void StartHome()
    {
        ScenesManager.Instance.LoadMainMenu();
    }
}
```

But buttons work only once, And when I go back to the LoadScene, I can't go back to the SampleScene.

And this is my SceneManager script:

```
using System.collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class ScenesManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static ScenesManager Instance;

    private void Awake()
    {

        Instance = this;
    }

    public enum Scene
    {

        SampleScene, LoadScene, Help
    }

    public void LoadScene(Scene scene)
    {

        SceneManager.LoadScene(Scene.ToString());

    }
    public void LoadMainMenu()
    {

        SceneManager.LoadScene(Scene.LoadScene.ToString());

    }
    public void LoadNewgame()
    {

        SceneManager.LoadScene(Scene.LoadScene.ToString());

    }

    public void HelpScene()
    {

        SceneManager.LoadScene(Scene.Help.ToString());

    }

}
```

Comment: Please include more details about the problem (e.g. Are there any errors thrown? Does everything load correctly when loading a scene?), and how you tried to fix it. You may want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information. Also if you can post the code with the apposite code tag, and not with images, that'd be better for the readers.

Comment: Please also dont put code as pictures

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You actually don't need this singleton at all ... it uses only static stuff -> this could be a `static class ScenesManager` ... do you really have two `UIGame` scripts with the same name? Do you get any exceptions? Maybe after renaming the `Button` field the reference got actually lost so the listener isn't attached in one of the scenes ...

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using AddListener, OnClick, and enums in your code. The way I would do it is to

1. Make a script (obviously)
2. Add the `using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;` namespace.
3. Set up a public function in the `SceneManager.cs` that loads the desired scene. For example:

   public void example (string sceneName){
   SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName);
   }
4. configure the OnClick feature on the button UI (scroll to the bottom of the component) and assign the function to it.

You also might want to debug your [singleton](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.entities@1.0/manual/components-singleton.html#:%7E:text=A%20singleton%20component%20is%20a,no%20longer%20a%20singleton%20component.). The way you set it up is that every time you load a new scene, you just have `public static ScenesManager instance = this` which won't work because you arent actually removing the new instance. So for example, on scene one, you have the instance, and then on scene two, you have two instances which are trying to occupy the static instance variable at the same time. Actually, the [singleton](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.entities@1.0/manual/components-singleton.html#:%7E:text=A%20singleton%20component%20is%20a,no%20longer%20a%20singleton%20component.) might not be needed at all, since the instance is just in your loaded scene. Singletons are usually in the `DontDestroyOnLoad()` scene.